# Pass by reference for structure in C

Tags: c

I want to pass a node by reference to a function and expect the variable in `main()` to be updated by the function

```
struct stack
{
    int item;
    struct stack *link;
};

void push(int item, struct stack *top)
{
  /* allocate memory and insert item*/  
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stack *top;
    push(10,top);
    printf("%d\n",top->item);
    return 0;
}
```

Here it displays 'segmentation fault', as if `top` did not get updated at all!

Comment: Add your definition of the function `push()` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for what you need to do, depending on whether your function allocates the stack or the `main()` function allocates the stack element.

#### Option 1 — `main()` allocates `top`

```
void push(int item, struct stack *top)
{
    top->link = 0;
    top->item = item;  
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stack top;    // Plain structure, not a pointer
    push(10, &top);      // Pass address of structure to function
    printf("%d\n", top.item);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work particularly well in the context of a stack, but can often be the correct way to process structures — the calling code allocates the structure and the called code uses the allocated structure.  Here is a dynamic allocation in the calling code, passed to the function to be initialized:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct stack *top = malloc(sizeof(*top));
    if (top != 0)
    {
        push(10, top);
        printf("%d\n", top->item);
        free(top);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Option 2 — `push()` allocates `top`

```
void push(int item, struct stack **top)
{
    struct stack *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->link = *top;
    node->item = item;
    *top = node;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stack *top = 0;   // Initialization is crucial
    push(10, &top);
    printf("%d\n", top->item);
    push(20, &top);
    printf("%d %d\n", top->item, top->link->item);
    free(top->link);
    free(top);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is weird because it uses fixed operations instead of loops, but is otherwise kosher.  All the code shown using `malloc()` has been tested with Valgrind and gets a clean bill of health.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pointer `top` in `main()` by reference to the function `push()`. So give the address of `top` not its value.

So use

```
push(10,&top);
```

instead of

```
push(10,top);
```

if the changes made to `top` in `push()` are to reflected back in `main()`.

This necessitates the modification of the function prototype. Use

```
void push(int item,struct stack **top)
```

instead of

```
void push(int item,struct stack *top)
```

And use `*top` in places where you used `top` in the `push()`.